# How I can use verb 'Wish' correctly?

Tags: verbs, differences, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, contractions

I thought that verb 'wish' we use to tell another person success or joy, etc. But I saw the sentence:

> I wish I could, but I don't want to.

Here it's being used about my regrets, isn't it?

How do I use the verb 'wish' correctly? Ex:
I wish I couldn't see him.
I wish he was here now.
She wishes she didn't live to New York.

Are these correct?

Answer (score 0):

Wish will often apply to hypothetical situations. That is to say situations that aren’t real (yet).

E.g. I wish I were a millionaire.

In the phrase

*I wish I could, but I don’t want to*

the context is important as the second half of the sentence could be referring to a consequence of having the wish granted.

For example.

A: Do you want to buy a Ferrari?
B: I wish I could, but I don’t want to [because I can’t afford it]

I wish I couldn't see him.
I wish he was here now.
She wishes she didn't live in New York.

Are all correct usage

E.g. I wish I couldn’t see him.

You can see him now, and you don’t want to.

Comment: _Wishing someone a happy birthday_ and the like is an extension of the same meaning - you would be pleased if they were to enjoy the day.